# EF6 Query across multiple many-to-many relationships

Tags: many-to-many, entity-framework-6

I have a group model that has a many-to-many relationship with two other models. Here is a simplified code first to help explain:

```
public class Store
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<StockGroup> StockGroups { get; set; }
}

public class StockItem
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<StockGroup> StockGroups { get; set; }
}

public class StockGroup 
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Store> Stores { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StockItem> StockItems { get; set; }
}
```

Using Fluent API I created a many-to-many relationship between Store and StockGroup as well as StockItem and StockGroup. This in turn creates two join tables.

The issue I am having is I cannot seem to create a query that spans from Store to StockItem or the reverse without using foreach loops.

For example: Given a single StockItem, I would like to know all the stores that are related to it through the StockGroup table. I tried something like this but what it is returning is a collection of a collection.

```
var stock = db.StockItems.Find(4);
var stores = stock.StockGroups.Select(g => g.Stores);
```

How can I rewrite this to combine the StockGroups to give me a collection of Stores?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SelectMany() to flatten the hierarchy:

```
var stores = stock.SelectMany(s => s.StockGroups).SelectMany(g => g.Stores).ToList();
```

http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2008/10/10/use-linqs-selectmany-method-to-flatten-collections/

Comment: SelectMany is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much! I actually accomplished what I wanted like this:

`var stores = stock.StockGroups.SelectMany(g => g.Stores).ToList();`